# How do I create a buffer with a list of org-id links for TODO items across all my org-agenda files?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-agenda

The basic pattern I'm looking for is how to loop across org-agenda files, select headings that are both TODOs and that have an :ID: property and not a :LISTED: property, and create a buffer just listing those IDs.

At the same time, I'd like to update the property drawer of the original items with a timestamp for the :LISTED: property indicating when it was listed in this manner.

The specific use case is a little more complicated, but I think I can figure out the details once I understand the pattern. What I need help with is the broader scaffolding: how to iterate over the files, do the matching and selection, create the buffer, copy, update the original property drawer, and so on.

Ultimately the new buffer becomes something like an HTML view of a subset of new action items, but (a) I need it to be formatted in a very specific way and (b) I am excited to use it as a practical way to write more complex elisp than I have so far.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated answer**

Here's a modification of the original answer that takes care of the setting of the `LISTED` property as well (which was hard to do with the `org-element` API). This version is very similar to the original version, except that it uses the [Mapping API](https://orgmode.org/manual/Using-the-Mapping-API.html) to do the traversal. The main function is `org-map-entries` which looks through a given `scope` (in this case, the scope is the whole file), using a predicate to consider only entries that match, and applies a user-defined function on each entry. The function takes no arguments: instead, `point` is set to the beginning of the entry in the buffer, so the choice of entry is implicit.

The update of the `LISTED` property is trivially done using the [Property API](https://orgmode.org/manual/Using-the-Mapping-API.html)'s `org-entry_put` and similarly the retrieval of the `ID` property uses `org-entry-get`. Both of these take a first argument that is the value of `point` or a marker, so they can be used to access properties away (even in a different file) from where you are right now; however, this solution does not need that generality, so they pass `nil` for that first argument (which makes it default to `point`).

Here are the two functions that are slightly different from the corresponding functions in the original solution:

```el
(defun do-something-with-buffer ()
  (org-map-entries #'do-something-with-headline "/+TODO" 'file))

(defun do-something-with-headline ()
  (let ((id (org-entry-get nil "ID"))
        (listed (org-entry-get nil "LISTED")))
    (when (and id (not listed))
      (org-entry-put nil "LISTED" 
                         (org-timestamp-format 
                            (org-timestamp-from-time (current-time) t)
                            (cdr org-time-stamp-formats)))
      id)))
```

The largest change is the formatting of the timestamp :-)

The other two functions (`my/org-agenda-list-of-ids` and the wrapper `my/write-list-to-buffer`) are unchanged.

BTW, although I kept the previous structure intact in order to demonstrate the similarities between the original and updated answers, the `scope` argument of `org-map-entries` would allow you to get rid of the loop over the agenda files:

```el
(defun my/org-agenda-list-of-ids ()
    (org-map-entries #'do-something-with-headline "/+TODO" 'agenda))
```

and you can get rid of the function `do-something-with-buffer`. The `agenda` scope maps over all agenda files as well as over all entries in each file. And incidentally the LOC has gone down from 18 to 11 lines :-)

---

**Original answer**

It takes surprisingly little code to do most of what you are looking for.
The traversal over agenda files is a simple loop; the matching and the selection is facilitated by some very powerful mapping functionality that Org mode implements in its parser, and the extraction of the properties is easy.

The following does all of the above - it does **not** implement the update of the property drawer (primarily because I don't know how to do that) and it does not create the buffer with the list of IDs, but given that the code below returns the list of IDs, creating a buffer and writing the list out is fairly trivial. I'll come back to that at the end of the post:

```el
(defun  my/org-agenda-list-of-ids()
  (let ((flist org-agenda-files)
        res)
    (while flist
      (with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect (car flist))
        (setq res (append res (do-something-with-buffer)))
        (setq flist (cdr flist))))
  res))

(defun do-something-with-buffer ()
  (org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer) 
                   'headline
                   #'do-something-with-headline))

(defun do-something-with-headline (el)
  (let ((todo (org-element-property :todo-keyword el))
        (id (org-element-property :ID el))
        (listed (org-element-property :LISTED el)))
    (when (and (string= todo "TODO") id (not listed))
      id)))
```

That's it: 18 lines of code.

The `my/org-agenda-list-of-ids` function is a simple loop over the agenda files. For every file, it selects the buffer of that file and makes it current and calls `do-something-with-buffer`. This function (see below for explanations) returns the list of IDs it finds in each headline of that buffer (provided that the headline passes some criteria that are implemented in the last function above). The body of the loop accumulates the list from each buffer into the `res` variable: it starts out empty and then we append to its previous value the list of IDs from the buffer at hand. We then chop off the first element of the file list and go to the top of the loop to continue with the rest of the file list.

The `do-something-with-buffer` function uses  two very powerful functions from the Org mode parser `org-element` API: the `org-element-parse-buffer` function parses the Org mode syntax of the buffer and returns a parse tree: an in-memory representation of the Org mode buffer that allows us to manipulate it. If you are familiar with the DOM in HTML and Javascript programming, it's directly analogous. The mapping function `org-element-map` is then applied to the parse tree: it selects only the `headline` elements and applies the given function `do-something-with-headline` to each such element. `org-element-map` accumulates the results of the function call on each element into a list that is then returned to its caller.

Finally, `do-something-with-headline` is given the element as its argument and has to figure out whether it satisfies the criteria. In this case, we get the values of the `TODO` keyword, `ID` property and the `LISTED` property of the element (if they exist) and then check whether to consider this element: if it has a `TODO` keyword whose value is "TODO" [1], an `ID` property value and does not have a `LISTED` property value, then we say "Bingo!" and return the value of the ID property. We can obviously do other tests here (is it scheduled? is there a deadline`? etc...)

And that's it - almost...

Now that we have a function that returns a list of all the IDs from all the headlines in all the agenda files that satisfy the criteria, all we need to do is write out the list into a buffer:

```el
(defun my/write-list-to-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((id-list (my/org-agenda-list-of-ids)))
    (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*List of IDs*")
      (delete-region (point-min) (point-max))
      (while id-list
        (insert (car id-list) "\n")
        (setq id-list (cdr id-list))))))
```

We first call `my/org-agenda-list-of-ids` to get the list of IDs from all the selected entries in all agenda files and remember it in `id-list`. We then get a buffer named `*List of IDs*` (we create it if necessary), clear it out in case there was an earlier list, and then loop over the `id-list`, inserting each ID followed by a newline into the buffer. All you have to do is switch to that buffer with `C-x b` and admire the list. It's pretty useless as it stands but presumably you will do other stuff to it to make it useful.

BTW, I declared this last function `interactive` so that you  can bind it to a key if you want:

```el
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c z") #'my/write-list-to-buffer)
```

You might want to put the keybinding on a different key map and/or on a different key, although `C-c z` tends to be unused (by [convention](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Conventions.html), such keys are left unassigned by packages, so that users can use them without worrying about clobbering some useful key binding).

As I mentioned, the only thing missing is the modification of each selected entry to add a `LISTED` property to it, so it will not be selected next time. I don't know how to do that using `org-element` (I've only used the parser in read-only mode, as in the above functions, so I don't know if there is a function already to modify the property drawer of the element - but then we also have to modify the buffer so that the change will eventually be written out to the file on disk.
If I find out how to do this, I may come back and add to this - or maybe somebody who knows how to do it off the top of their head can provide their own answer (or modify this one).

---

[1] This may or may not be what you want but is easily modified: e.g if any `TODO` keyword will do, all you have to check is that `todo` is not `nil`: `(when (and todo id (not listed))...`; or maybe you want the `TODO` keyword to be anything except `DONE` which would be written as `(when (and todo (not (string= todo "DONE")) id (not listed)....`.

---

**EDIT** after mulling it over: after looking at the `org-element` API for a while, I think it is hard to use the API to *change* things: apparently, `org-element-map` passes to the function it calls on each element, a *copy* of, rather than a reference to, the element, so it is (AFAICT) not possible to make a change within that function that will be reflected in the parse tree. It is also the case that, although you can convert the parse tree to a string that represents the Org mode file, the string is a *canonical* representation of the file, so it will change things in the file (e.g. the case of keywords is canonicalized to lower case). The `org-element` API is good for read-only access to the file.

There is another mapping function, `org-map-entries` (see [Using the mapping API](https://orgmode.org/manual/Using-the-Mapping-API.html) in the manual) that operates directly on the buffer of a file, rather than parsing the file into an in-memory parse tree. That allows easy use of the [Property API](https://orgmode.org/manual/Using-the-Property-API.html), i.e. `org-entry-{get,put}` as you surmised, and therefore makes changing things much easier. The structure of the solution is pretty much the same as above, but there are obviously differences in detail. If I find some time, I'll write up an answer along those lines.

Another possibility is a hybrid solution: using information from the element, we can sneak out and using that information go and modify the corresponding structure in the buffer. The trouble with that is that the obvious place to make the change is deep into the traversal of the parse tree - but if we change the buffer, we invalidate the parse tree. It might be easier to remember the elements that we want to change (not just the ids); then in a final pass, we traverse the list of those elements and make the property changes to the buffer that gave rise to each of those elements, and also write the ids to its own buffer. Again, if I find some time, I'll take a crack at this.

Comment: Wow, thank you for such a detailed and helpful response!

I'm guessing that the functions in [Using the Property API](https://orgmode.org/manual/Using-the-Property-API.html) from the org manual have everything I need to verify, get, and set the LISTED property.

Probably the first question is going to be how org-entry-get is different than org-element-property and why.

Let me leave this open for a bit to see if anyone has the key to the property-setting part. But this is fantastic; thank you so much for the help!

Comment: See the EDIT for some possibilities.

Comment: Updated the answer with the `Mapping API` solution. PTAL. I'm not sure I'll do the hybrid :-)

Comment: You have been so much help! This is wonderful. Agree with your thinking about modifying things in place; in a way, I guess the problem is similar to changing or deleting the keys of a dictionary as you iterate over it should be solvable using similar techniques. Thanks to your help I am looking forward to seeing how this project unfolds!

Comment: PTAL again. I added an even simpler method that uses `org-map-entries` to implicitly loop over the agenda files, so you don't need the explicit loop. Untested, but it should work: if you have problems, let me know.

Comment: 11 lines! That is beautiful.. thank you! I am playing in my scratch buffer now. ☺️